# Display a tile from Power BI within an Iframe c#

Tags: javascript, c#, iframe, razor, powerbi

I am wondering if anyone could help me I am trying to embed a tile from power bi into a i-frame. I have tried many approaches and I just seems to end up getting nothing or just the loading sign none stop. This code below I just see nothing. Also is there a way of doing this without using java-script.?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var width = 800;
    var height = 600;
    var embedTileUrl = @Model.Tile.embedUrl;
    var accessToken  = @Model.AccessToken;

    window.onload = function () {
        updateEmbedTile();
    };

    function updateEmbedTile() {
        if ("" === embedTileUrl)
            return;
        iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameEmbedTile');
        iframe.src = embedTileUrl + "&width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
        iframe.onload = postActionLoadTile;
    }

    function postActionLoadTile() {
        if ("" === accessToken)
            return;
        var h = height;
        var w = width;
        var m = { action: "loadTile", accessToken: accessToken, height: h, width: w };
        message = JSON.stringify(m);
        iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameEmbedTile');
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
    }
     </script>

    <iframe id="iFrameEmbedTile" src="" height="500px" width="500px" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you able to use the same App (clientID and clientSecret) to make the sample work? The sample is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms/embed-a-tile-into-an-app

Comment: Yes works 100% the sample app, but the sample is not very clear to  me on this point. Is there a simple implementation of this...? or even better a non java-script example..?

Comment: Can you check that the accessToken is a string literal not an object of  some kind? Also does the postActionLoadTile method get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These changes fixed it in the end, as a fast fix but I intend to investigate this further and find a better solution not using Javascript.

Fixed the first issue:

```
 var accessTokenElement = "@Model.AccessToken";
```

Fixed the second issue:

```
<input type="text" id="tb_EmbedURL" value="@Model.Tile.embedUrl" hidden />
<input type="button" id="bEmbedTileAction" value="Embed Tile" hidden />
<iframe id="iFrameEmbedTile" src="" height="450" width="450" frameborder="0" align="middle" seamless></iframe>
```

This loads the automatically. Below is the code in its totality

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var el = document.getElementById("bEmbedTileAction");
        if (el.addEventListener) {
            el.addEventListener("click", updateEmbedTile, false);
        } else {
            el.attachEvent('onclick', updateEmbedTile);
        }

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
        } else {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);
        }

        var accessTokenElement = "@Model.AccessToken";
        if (null !== accessTokenElement) {
            var accessToken = accessTokenElement.value;
            if ("" !== accessToken)
                updateEmbedTile();
        }
    };

    var width  = 450;
    var height = 450;

    function receiveMessage(event) {
        if (event.data) {
            try {
                messageData = JSON.parse(event.data);
                if (messageData.event === "tileClicked") {
                    //Get IFrame source and construct dashboard url
                    iFrameSrc = document.getElementById(event.srcElement.iframe.id).src;

                    //Split IFrame source to get dashboard id
                    var dashboardId = iFrameSrc.split("dashboardId=")[1].split("&")[0];

                    urlVal = iFrameSrc.split("/embed")[0] + "/dashboards/{0}";
                    urlVal = urlVal.replace("{0}", dashboardId);

                    window.open(urlVal);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                // In a production app, handle exception
            }
        }
    }

    function updateEmbedTile() {
        // check if the embed url was selected
        var embedTileUrl = document.getElementById('tb_EmbedURL').value;
        if ("" === embedTileUrl)
            return;

        iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameEmbedTile');
        iframe.src = embedTileUrl + "&width=" + width + "&height=" + height;
        iframe.onload = postActionLoadTile;
    }


    function postActionLoadTile() {
        accessToken = "@Model.AccessToken";

        if ("" === accessToken)
            return;

        var h = height;
        var w = width;

        var m = { action: "loadTile", accessToken: accessToken, height: h, width: w };
        message = JSON.stringify(m);

        iframe = document.getElementById('iFrameEmbedTile');
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");;
    }

</script>

<input type="text" id="tb_EmbedURL" value="@Model.Tile.embedUrl" hidden />
<input type="button" id="bEmbedTileAction" value="Embed Tile" hidden />
<iframe id="iFrameEmbedTile" src="" height="450" width="450" frameborder="0" align="middle" seamless></iframe>
```

Comment: I had similar issues like this, the documentation for  tiles is not great. Nice to see some good examples in C#

Answer (score 0):

The power bi tile embedding api requires you to load the embed page and pass the parameters as shown in the sample I reference in my earlier comment. You can do this using javascript in a browser, but I've seen at least one example where someone did it in an android app with just the tile hosted in a web browser control. Similarly it should be possible to use a web view in a windows universal app, use the navigate method to load the ifame url directly, get notified the tile page loaded using scriptnotify, then pass the postmessage using invokescriptasync. If that doesn't directly work then you'd use navigatetostring to place a .js method on the page that passes the post message to an iframe.  I've not had a chance to play with this myself yet. If you get it working would love to see a gist of your work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview